# Cannot build ionic project due to ANDROID_HOME path issues

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I use linux mint. I set the path on `~/.bash_profile` like:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/mss/android-sdks
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

When I build ionic project on android :-

```
lenovo-g50 ~/IONIC/apps $ cordova run android
```

Running command:

```
/home/mss/IONIC/apps/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/mss/IONIC/apps
```

Add to body class: platform-android
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Please check that your environment variables are really set. `echo $ANDROID_HOME` should print: `/home/mss/android-sdks`. If not check the filename of your `.bash_profile`. You might have to login again (or start anoter shell) after changing anything in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: lenovo-g50 ~ $ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/mss/android-sdks/platform-tools

Comment: `/home/mss/android-sdks/platform-tools` would be wrong? It should be `/home/mss/android-sdks`, nor?

Comment: but at this time when i open .bash_profile here is nothing, blank file show what can i do ?

Comment: Please check that you opened: `~/.bash_profile` If you open `.bash_profile` and you are not in you home directory, then it is just a different file.

Answer (score 2):

in  windows OS

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

IN  mac

`export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/userName/Documents/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:/Users/userName/Documents/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools`

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the sdk. I think your environment variable are set properly, but you don't have the required SDK. type `android -v` in your console and it start the SDK manager or you can start it manualy in *ANDROID_HOME* directory. You need to install several build tools and in minimum one SDK Platform.

Comment: i have full sdk directory but when i give the path that says set home variable path

Comment: try to add `ANDROID_HOME` to the path